# Using Eclipse with PyWin32

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, web2py, pywin32

I am running Eclipse (Indigo) with PyDev, Python 2.6 and PyWin32 (build 217, 32 bit), and having a problem that gets stranger the more I investigate.

I'm running a Python program that imports the following 3 libraries:

```
import win32con
import win32file
import pywintypes
```

win32con imports properly but win32file does not (note: win32con is a pyc and win32file is a pyd, in raw Python):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....\dynamic\testpywin32.py", line 2, in <module>
    import win32file
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried the equivalent in pure Python 2.6 (IDLE) and everything imported properly.

Comparing sys.path in IDLE and Eclipse, the only thing not in Eclipse is ['C:\Python26\Lib\idlelib']; the only extra thing Eclipse has (besides the workspace) is C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.2.4.2011121401\pysrc.

In addition, I went on and used the following commands right after startup, through the debugger:

```
sys.path = [sys.path from IDLE]
os.environ['PATH'] = [os.environ['PATH'] from IDLE]
```

which didn't seem to help.

What's going on here?

Comment: Have you tried checking if other environment variables also match from the console to Eclipse (such as PATH or LIBPATH)?

Comment: Good point! I'll add that here.

Comment: No LIBPATH on Windows, but tried changing PATH+PYTHONPATH.

Comment: You're having that error when running in the pydev debugger... if you run without the debugger, you still have that error?

Answer (score 0):

which windows version are you using??

i am using windows XP + pydev plugin and its works.

go to python path and try to fix the python eggs path, and press apply

Comment: Windows 7. We already tried to alter PATH and PYTHONPATH, as was mentioned above in the question. If you are suggesting a specific set of commands or other options, please describe them in more detail so others can use the information.